# jquery slider max value in zero decimal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

Here I have a problem with jQuery slider, were I get `min` and `max` values dynamically from a API, so when the value of `max`, is in zero floating (like 0.27...), then I can not move the slider from left to right.

Please have a look into the attached image

[image]

in this, the first input box (min) holds the value zero, and the second input box (max) holds the value zero floating (0.27...)
In this case i can not drag the slider left to right,

```
var calculateStep = function (minVal, maxVal) {
    var difference = maxVal - minVal;
    var step = parseInt(difference / 100);
    return step;
};
var sliderStep = calculateStep(cfg.minVal, cfg.maxVal);
$(filter_wrap).find('.slider').slider({
    range: true,
    min: cfg.minVal,
    max: cfg.maxVal,
    step: sliderStep,
    values: [cfg.minVal, cfg.maxVal],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      //some code here
   }
});
```

The function `calculateStep` should be have logic to handle any kind of `min`and `max`, I think, but not sure, how to handle it.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing

```
var step = parseInt(difference / 100);
```

to

```
var step = parseFloat(difference / 100);
```